# How can I get a list of accounts for users that have logged onto a machine?

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way, to find out, which users have ever been logged on a local windows 10 machine by using PowerShell.

By using

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"
```

I get a list of users, but I think this is not complete, because there are more home directories than the list says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get all the cached accounts that has been logged into a computer. Note that there are ways to clear this, so there's the possibillity that someone else has been logged in, but cleared the traces. Make sure to run as administrator if `lastusetime` is of interest.

```
Get-CimInstance win32_userprofile -verbose | Select localpath, lastusetime
```

(You can remove `-verbose` if you don't want the operation to show, and of course `Select` for the stuff you are interested in)